# Correct Google Sheets Autofill - Skipping Cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to have a spreadsheet with a second standings chart that references a lot of different information on the sheet; I'm trying to average a range of a row of cells, but the rows that have the numbers I'm using are 5 rows apart.

```
=AVERAGE(C3:Q3)
=AVERAGE(C9:Q9)
=AVERAGE(C15:Q15)
```

This repeats for a while, but every time I try to autofill the rest of the cells with this formula, it never continues the pattern of skipping rows, and instead fills in rows between the gaps. How can I make the autofill follow the pattern I need it to? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating those averages with `sumif()` and `countif()`, and take only every sixth row with `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    iferror( 
      sumif( if(column(C3:Q), row(C3:Q)), row(C3:Q), C3:Q ) 
      / 
      (columns(C3:Q) - countif(C3:Q & "→" & row(C3:Q), "→" & row(C3:Q))) 
    ), 
    "skipping 6", 0 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164795/) is excellent and provides a single arrayformula to return all your values.

> can I make the autofill follow the pattern I need it to?

## Yes you can

The following formula can be auto-filled:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-3,6)=0,
   AVERAGE(C3:Q3), IFERROR(1/0))
```

## Explanation

In order to work as you wish, the formula needs a way to perform one behavior on certain rows, and a different behavior on all others.

You can leverage the row numbers where you want the AVERAGE function applied because they follow a pattern.

They are all divisible by 6 without remainder after subtracting 3. For example if you subtract 3 from the row numbers 3, 9, 15, 21, you are left with 0, 6, 12, 18

Alternatively, if you subtract 3 from other row numbers like 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, you are left with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11.

## MOD Function

The MOD function is ideally suited as its purpose is to return the remainder of a dividend and its divisor. 
`MOD(dividend,divisor)`

So `MOD(ROW()-3,6)` will equal zero on all the rows where you want the calculation performed.

Using `MOD(ROW()-3,6)=0` as the test in an IF function will allow you to return your formula `AVERAGE(C3:Q3)` where it is TRUE or nothing if it is an in-between row and FALSE.

You could use a pair of double-quotes `""` for nothing but in Sheets `IFERROR(1/0)` is the way to properly return "nothing"